# Customizing CRUD module

Tags: playframework, crud

I'm using CRUD module for my application which creates a search engine. I want to customize the module so that the search results appearing would redirect me to another page. I tried the documentation http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/crud but it didn't help much.
I'm following this video to create my search engine http://geeks.aretotally.in/play-elastic-search-module-new-0-0-5-release-with-screencast 
 [image: ![this is a screen shot of my search so far when i clock on the search results in this case "tutorial [2]" i get this page![][1]]

i've a problem with the routes so i want to know how can i when i click on the search results to redirect me to another page

I've added this line to the routes

GET     /Tutorials/:id                         Tutorials.tutorialPage(tutId: Long)

and I already have this method in the controllers:

```
public static void tutorialPage(long tutId) {
        Tutorial t = Tutorial.findById(tutId);
        render(t);
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. code samples, examples, errors...

Comment: i added some code and a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Play' s CRUD module is actually intended to generate an admin console. What you store in your database can directly be editted, new data can be added and your data can be deleted by the use of the pages, generated by CRUD module.

If you want to customize the pages, that are generated by the CRUD module, you need to change the pages that are inside the play/modules/crud folder

[image]

Comment: ok i understand that, i mean in the above screenshot when i click on the search results i get error in the routing so i want it to redirect me to another page when i click on it

Comment: I tried to customize the list view but i can't pass the object id: it gives me a null pointer exception
<a href=" /app/controllers/Tutorials/tutorialPage?tutId=object._key()"

Comment: Your screenshot is so small that I can not see what is written. As far as I estimate, you have a Search Results button on one of your CRUD pages and you want to redirect the user if this button is clicked. The simplest way to do this is that, go to this CRUD page' s html, use DOM selection and unbind click action for this button(with JQuery) for example `$("#searchResults").unbind("click");` and then give another click action to it as in `$("#searchResults").click(function() {window.location.replace("/where_u_want")});`